# Visual Studio / Nuget puts files in the wrong place

Tags: tfs, nuget, visual-studio-2022, nlog

New-ish to ASP.NET Core and VS 2022. Clearly it is doing things differently than previous versions.

I added NLog to my project and everything works great. However, to get the intellisense for the config file I added NLog.xsd via Nuget (NLog.Schema 5.2.4).  When I load the solution or add another item to the project I get an error message pop up telling me I can't add the file to my project because it's not in source control.

The error message is about NLog.xsd or this vspscc file and not the new file I am adding. VS must be doing some housekeeping whenever you add a new item - in this case a razor page.

So I look at NLog.xsd in its visual studio properties and it is located in my personal one drive folder on c: instead of my project folder on f: which is tracked by TFS/Devops.  Why does it do this? Do I need to remove the file and manually drag it over from the NuGet dump location?  Same with ProjectName.csproj.vspscc, which honestly I'm not sure should be part of the actual project anyway but I don't remember adding it so must be automatic.

Comment: Is your project using `PackageReference`s? Older versions of NuGet used a packages.config file and cached the packages under the solution folder. That has been superseded by [`PackageReference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files)s in the project file and packages are cached under the user account and shared globally across all solutions and projects. See [GeneratePathProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#generatepathproperty) to get a property for the path to the package

Comment: @JonathanDodds I am not sure but what I'm saying is that previous iterations of this same package put the .xsd file directly into my project. It was not ever in the packages folder it was assigned as a file that was part of the project. And initially it does add the file to the project and has the little "checked out" icon next to it, but at some point in the process it can't check in because the file doesn't actually exist in the project because it's out in onedrive. I guess if that's the way it's supposed to work now, fine, but it would be nice if VS didn't complain, then.